# Error while merging and converting two markdown files to pdf using pandoc

Tags: pandoc, compilation-error, markdown

I'm using to pandoc to create pdf via following command:

> pandoc -s -o analysis.pdf latex_header.md Analysis.md

The following error is shown :

> Error producing PDF.
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.129 ...uence of real number is a function,(f:\N

Content of latex_header.md

> $$
> \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
> \newcommand{\com}{\mathbb{C}}
> \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
> \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
> \newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}
> \newcommand{\sequence}[1]{(#1_n)*{n=1}^{\infty}}
>
> \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left{#1\right}}
>
> \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
>
> \newcommand{\pdiff}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
>
> \newcommand{\diff}[3]{\frac{d^{#3}#1}{d#2^{#3}}}
>
> \newcommand{\summ}[2]{\sum*{#1}^{#2}}
> \newcommand{\fbraks}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
> \newcommand{\tbraks}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
> $$

The line in Analysis.md where the error is creeping in:

> 1. A sequence of real number is a function,$f:\N \ra \R$ . Commonly represented as $\sequence{a} = \braces{a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots}$.

I also used the pandoc to get the intermediate [tex](https://github.com/SAHOO98/Mathematics_notes/blob/master/analysis.tex). I can see the problem in line 61 and 75 of the tex file `\[...\]`. I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

The error arises from your `\braces` command: use `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace` as delimiters.

In addition, still in the latex_header.md, the `$$` are useless.